# How to handle some asynchronous TcpClient responses?

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, tcp

I use [this class for asynchronous client-server TCP network connection](https://github.com/Phyyl/ObooltNet/blob/master/Source/ObooltNet/NetConnection.cs) in my project.

I most connect to "`Remote server`" and send and receive data over TCP connection (*from another company that we can't change communication method except TCP*) in a "`Interface Web Service`".

This "`Interface Web Service`" handle "`Client Apps`" requests, create data and pass to "`Remote server`" over TCP connection, and pass (response) parsed response of "`Remote server`" to "`Client Apps`".

Note that current TCP connection, receive "`Remote server`" responses with **`OnDataReceived`** event. (This event is good and I want to use this event for next steps).

How can access and handle these asynchronous responses and pass complete response for "`Client Apps`" requests?

For summarize:

1. `Client app` send request to `Interface service`
2. `Interface service` create command for `Remote server`
3. `Remote server` response to command from `Interface service`
4. Now in `Interface service`, response handled with **`OnDataReceived`** EVENT, that I can not access it from `Interface service` that handle `Client App` request. Problem is here...

---

Look at this image to understand my scenario:

[image: Scenario of communications]

Comment: I'm really unclear on what the problem is that you are having. Can you elaborate considerably? What have you tried so far? Can you post short code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi @usr. I want to "Interface Service" always connect to "Remote Server" and process data transfer between theme. I used from class that handle messages received from "Remote Server" by **OnDataReceived ** event (that linked to it in question). Now, when a request received from "Client application" comes to "Interface service", and "Interface service" translate and pass it to "Remote server", response of "Remote Server" handled by event, that I can't access to it across Method that is handling "Client Application".

How to access data received from event?

Comment: Why are you working on the TCP layer (is it a requirement for the course?)? Generally people will use some kind of abstraction on top of an abstraction ....of the TCP layer. For example WCF implementing SOAP over HTTP over TCP.

Comment: Hi @Aron. Yes, it's "Remote server" requirement and I most communicate via TCP. :(

Comment: My point is that you will almost never work at the TCP layer. So why are you doing so?

Comment: @Aron, the "Remote Server" is from another company, that we can't force theme to change TCP layer communication to newer methods like SOAP or WCF.

Comment: In that case you don't have nearly enough information here for me to do the work. You haven't described what a complete response means. Even if you did, 50rep is too little for me to write the proprietary  connector for you. This is consultancy work.

Comment: Actually what is the problem? Why cannot you do following inside web service method implementation: 1. Connect to "remote service" 2. Send request 3. Wait for response 4. Transfer resposnse back to client.?

Comment: No problem to get a web request on your webservice, connect to your bakcend to get a bytestream via tcp, either async or not, but please share your code you already have for the webservice. What is unclear to you about the implementation?

Comment: Hi @TimurMannapov. My problem is with Step 3 in your comment.
Look at the Question, I add link to C# Class (NetConnection.cs) that used in project. In this class, waiting for TCP response was implemented with Task method that raise "OnDataReceived" event.
So I can't handle raised event within Web service method!

Comment: Hi @NielsV and thanks for your reply. please visit my previous comment.

Comment: let me first say that you've provided entirely too much irrelevant information... you've stated: "...I can not access it from Interface service that handle Client App request".. "I can't access to it across Method that is handling "Client Application".. explain why. you said you're using that public (non-sealed) class, so you can inherit it, override it, or simple handle the event in manner that provides you access.. what is keeping you from assigning the `byte[]` value to static global variable and setting a flag? how are you initializing the NetConnection class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for reading and try to help me.

I solve this problem by edit **"NetConnection.cs"** class and add this method:

```
public Task<byte[]> SendAndReceiveData(byte[] data, int timeout = 10000)
{
    CheckServerUsedAsClient();
    client.GetStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    Task<byte[]> tskReceive = ReceiveFromAsync(this, timeout, true);
    tskReceive.Wait();

    return tskReceive;
}
```

and using this method to send request and receive data from "Remote server" like this:

```
byte[] requestData = createByteArrayCommand();
Task<byte[]> testTask = netConnectionObj.SendAndReceiveData(requestData);
testTask.Wait();

// testTask.Result <= contains server response
```

Comment: it's been some time, but this actually should use `async` and `await` `public async Task<byte[]> SendAndReceiveData(byte[] data, int timeout = 10000)` in method and `return await RecieveFromAsync(this, timeout, true);` instead of `.wait();`

Answer (score 5):

please review the following complete (yet, not optimal) working sample of that class.

note the while loop in the `MyHandler.ProcessRequest` method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {

        private static NetConnection fakeServerConnector { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pageHandler = new MyHandler();
            var tw = Console.Out;
            var builder = new UriBuilder();
            builder.Host = "localhost";
            builder.Port = 80;
            builder.Query = "";

            initFakeServer(8080);

            pageHandler.ProcessRequest(
                new HttpContext(
                    new HttpRequest("index.html", builder.ToString(), ""),
                    new HttpResponse(tw))
                    );

            ConsoleKey key;
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Press [Enter] or [Esc] to exit!");
            do
            {
                key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            } while (!(key == ConsoleKey.Enter || key == ConsoleKey.Escape));
        }

        private static void initFakeServer(int Port)
        {
            fakeServerConnector = new NetConnection();
            fakeServerConnector.OnDataReceived += fakeServerConnector_OnDataReceived;
            fakeServerConnector.Start(Port);

        }

        static void fakeServerConnector_OnDataReceived(object sender, NetConnection connection, byte[] e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e));
            var msg = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Fake Server says: \"Hi\"");
            connection.Send(msg);
        }
    }

    public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public string HostName { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        private NetConnection clientConnector { get; set; }
        private bool isReceived;
        private byte[] responsePayload;

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }



        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {            
            HostName = "localhost";
            Port = 8080;

            clientConnector = new NetConnection();
            clientConnector.OnDataReceived += OnDataReceivedHandler;
            clientConnector.Connect(HostName, Port);
            clientConnector.Send(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Client Connector says: \"Hello World\""));
            while (!isReceived)
            {
                // do nothing; wait for isReceived to become true;
            }
            var responsePayloadText = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(responsePayload, 0, responsePayload.Length);
            context.Response.Write(responsePayloadText + Environment.NewLine);
        }


        public void OnDataReceivedHandler(object sender, NetConnection connection, byte[] data)
        {
            isReceived = true;
            responsePayload = data;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: note, to test this code sample.. make a new console project, add assembly `system.web`, copy and paste "***NetConnection.cs***" class into the project.

Comment: Hi @Brett Caswell.
Thanks for your reply, and thanks for good solution.
I solve this problem by simple modify of "NetConnection.cs" class that posted in my Answer.
Thanks.

Comment: no problem @SayedAbolfazlFatemi, glad I could help.. I figured the better solution was going to involve `Task` and `Async`; and I figured the optimal way would be to modifiy, inherit, overload, or encapsulate the `NetConnection` class, as you had done in your own solution..

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I test it and work very well, is ***[SignalR](http://signalr.net/)***.

With SignalR hub we can call a method on `Interface Web Service` that is like receive request from `Client Applications` and then create TCP request to `Remote server`.

After receive response from `Remote server` (raise **`OnDataReceive(byte[])`**), call a method on `Client Applications` and pass response.